Rotational property of multiplying complex numbers together: wanted to know if $\theta$ referred to the $\operatorname{Arg}$ or $\operatorname{arg}$

Hi guys.
This theorem in my textbook is about the rotational property of multiplying complex numbers together. I wanted to know if $\theta$ referred to the $\operatorname{Arg}$ (principal angle) or $\operatorname{arg}$ (angle with respect to positive $x$-axis). Does it work for both? What if we were dividing the complex number?
This thread did not answer my question. The ticked answer said the theorem referred to $\theta$ as simply the $\operatorname{arg}$. But all I think it was saying was that: we use $\operatorname{arg}$, not $\operatorname{Arg}$, to refer to $\theta$, because, for some cases of $z$ and $w$ expressed in $\operatorname{Arg}$, the resulting angle will not be in the $\operatorname{Arg}$ domain $(-\pi, \pi]$ hence causing notational inconsistency, hence we use $\operatorname{arg}$.
I tried testing if the theorem still worked on two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ below the $x$-axis for whose resulting complex number $z/w$ I knew. And it worked for whether the angles of the complex numbers were $\operatorname{Arg}$ or $\operatorname{arg}$ either way. At least for me it did.
Thanks guys.
UPDATE: BOTH ANSWERS WRITTEN ARE VERY HELPFUL AND I GET IT NOW. UNFORTUNATELY THERE IS NO OPTION TO UPVOTE 2+ ANSWERS.

It will be arg (lowercase) so that the rule (as written) applies in general. Consider, for instance, rotating $z=-i$ through an angle of $\pi$ anti-clockwise.

If it is true for every real $\theta$ (which it is) then it will be true for every $\theta$ in $(-\pi,\pi]$. As you know, the result is not necessarily principal argument because you could, for example, be adding $\pi$ to $\pi$. So if you want the principal argument of the result you sometimes have to add or subtract $2\pi$.

The statement is true for any $\theta$ such that $w = r\operatorname{cis} \theta$. Thus it is irrelevant whether you take $\theta = \operatorname{Arg} \in (-\pi, \pi]$ or $\theta = \operatorname{arg} w \in [0,2\pi)$ or something else.
The equation
$$w = r\operatorname{cis} \theta \tag{1}$$
determines $\theta$ only up to a summand $2k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb Z$. Both a clockwise and an anti-clockwise rotation by the angle $2\pi$ are the identity operation, thus all solutions of $(1)$ result in the same operation when applied to $z$.
In particulur we can "normalize" the choice of $\theta$ by requiring that it is the unique solution of $(1)$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ or alternatively the unique solution of $(1)$ in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.
When $w$ is contained in the closed upper half-plane ($\operatorname{Im}w\ge 0$), then we have $\operatorname{Arg} w = \operatorname{arg} w \in [0,\pi ]$.
When $w$ is contained in the open lower half-plane ($\operatorname{Im}w < 0$), then we have $\operatorname{Arg} w  \in (-\pi,0)$, $\operatorname{arg} w  \in (\pi,2\pi)$ and $\operatorname{arg} w  = \operatorname{Arg} w + 2\pi$. What does this mean geometrically? An anti-clockwise rotation by an angle $\theta \in (\pi,2\pi)$ is nothing else than an anti-clockwise rotation by $\theta - 2\pi \in (-\pi,0)$ which is the same as a clockwise rotation by $2\pi - \theta$.

Commonly, when we talk about the (non-principal) argument of $z$, we are not talking about restricting the angle to a particular domain but instead talking about the multi-valued argument, i.e. the set of all angles $\theta$ such that $z = r \operatorname{cis} \theta$ holds. This is important for things like multiplication and division because any choice of restricted domain for the argument will cause problems.
For example, if we have
$$(r \operatorname{cis} \theta) \times (s \operatorname{cis} \phi) = (rs) \operatorname{cis} (\theta + \phi)$$
then if $\theta, \phi \in [0, 2 \pi)$ then $\theta + \phi \in [0, 4 \pi)$. But if $\theta, \phi \in [-\pi, \pi)$ then $\theta + \phi \in [-2 \pi, 2 \pi)$.
Instead, if we treat both $\theta$ and $\phi$ as multivalued, so $\theta = \theta_0 + 2n \pi$ and $\phi = \phi_0 + 2m \pi$ with $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then adding those together to get $\theta + \phi = \theta_0 + \phi_0 + 2k \pi$ gives the right multi-valued result, from which you can then pick the principal argument by choosing the right value of $k$.
